# Sort by number of subdocuments mongoid

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a model `Person` that has many `Comments`

How could I sort people collection by number of `comments`

Something like

> Person.desc(:"comments.count")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really work with two collections at once so you need to something in `Person` can you can sort on. The usual approach is to use a counter cache to cache the number of comments in each `Person`. You'd have something like this:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :comments
end
class Comment
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :person, :counter_cache => true
end
```

The `:counter_cache => true` option to `belongs_to` will add a `comments_count` field to `Person` which will contain the cached number of comments.

Once you have your counter cache, you can say:

```
Person.desc('comments_count')
```

to get your sorting.

You'll need to initialize the counters by hand using [`Person.reset_counters`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/CounterCache/ClassMethods:reset_counters) or [`Person#reset_counters`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/CounterCache:reset_counters) to get things started.

Comment: Your comments are embedded in your people so your comments are about your people? I think a counter cache is still the cleanest approach.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at orderby functionality in the mongo docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/